# Where is function Empty() {}?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome,

```
(function(){}).__proto__
```

is

```
function Empty() {}
```

so I would have expected

```
new Function();
```

to be `function Empty() {}`, but instead it is `function anonymous() {}`.

Where can I find `function Empty() {}`? Is it in `Function` or `Object` somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those names don't mean you can access them with those identifiers.

As for the prototype of a function, the name is [set at startup](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/bootstrapper.cc#489). That function has been set a name but it doesn't really serve any purpose other than `.name` and `.toString()` exposing it.

As for a `new Function()` instance, the name is merely [printed for `.toString()`](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/v8natives.js#1565). So `.name` is still the empty string. Again, it doesn't serve much purpose.

Answer (score 6):

An empty function object (whose name is `Empty`) is the prototype of the `Function`.

```
Function.prototype.toString() === "function Empty() {}"

Object.getPrototypeOf(new Function()).toString() === "function Empty() {}"
```

Comment: Thanks. What about `function anonymous() {}`?

Comment: @Randomblue `new Function().toString()` will give you that.

Answer (score 2):

Empty is the name of Function's prototype. From the Chrome console:

```
dir(Function)
  function Function() { [native code] }
  arguments: null
  caller: null
  length: 1
  name: "Function"
    prototype: function Empty() {}
    __proto__: function Empty() {}
    apply: function apply() { [native code] }
    arguments: null
    bind: function bind() { [native code] }
    call: function call() { [native code] }
    caller: null
    constructor: function Function() { [native code] }
    length: 0
    name: "Empty"
    toString: function toString() { [native code] }
    __proto__: Object
```